# Loop so program repeats

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

Im writing a program for python that should convert binary to equivalent hex and decimal values. The problem is I need to set up a loop so that the whole program repeats until the user picks the quit option. Heres my code:

```
denary = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
binary = ["0000", "0001", "0010", "0011", "0100", "0101", "0110", "0111", "1000", "1001", "1010", "1011", "1100", "1101", "1110", "1111"]
hexadecimal = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]

print("What would you like to do today?\n1. Print values\n2. Convert denary values between 0 and 15 to binary and hex values\n3. Convert hex values between 0 and 15 to binary and denary values\n9. Quit")

option = int(input("Input Choice: "))
if option == 1:
print("denary", "binary", "hexadecimal")
for row in zip(denary, binary, hexadecimal):
    print ("      ".join(row))

elif option == 2:
    denary = int(input("Enter a denary number: "))
    index = denary
    print("Binary: ", binary[index])
    print("Hexadecimal: ", hexadecimal[index])

elif option == 3:
    hex=(input("Enter a hex number: "))
    if hex=="a":
         print("Denary: ", denary[10])
         print("Binary: ", binary[10])
elif hex=="b":
         print("Denary: ", denary[11])
         print("Binary: ", binary[11])
elif hex=="c":
         print("Denary: ", denary[12])
         print("Binary: ", binary[12])
elif hex=="d":
         print("Denary: ", denary[13])
         print("Binary: ", binary[13])
elif hex=="e":
         print("Denary: ", denary[14])
         print("Binary: ", binary[14])
elif hex=="f":
         print("Denary: ", denary[15])
         print("Binary: ", binary[15])
elif hex=="1":
         print("Denary: ", denary[1])
         print("Binary: ", binary[1])
elif hex=="2":
         print ("Denary: ", denary[2])
         print ("Binary: ", binary[2])
elif hex=="3":
         print ("Denary: ", denary[3])
         print ("Binary: ", binary[3])
elif hex=="4":
         print ("Denary: ", denary[4])
         print ("Binary: ", binary[4])
elif hex=="5":
         print ("Denary: ", denary[5])
         print ("Binary: ", binary[5])
elif hex=="6":
         print ("Denary: ", denary[6])
         print ("Binary: ", binary[6])
elif hex=="7":
         print ("Denary: ", denary[7])
         print ("Binary: ", binary[7])
elif hex=="8":
         print ("Denary: ", denary[8])
         print ("Binary: ", binary[8])
elif hex=="9":
         print ("Denary: ", denary[9])
         print ("Binary: ", binary[9])

elif option ==9:
quit()
```

Does anyone know where to put the loop so that it would repeat until the quit option is picked?

Thanks.

Comment: Above the first print call.

Comment: You seem to have a few formatting issues.

Comment: Malik - could you elaborate please?

Comment: and sweeneyrod how would I word that?

Answer (score 1):

Just do it like this

```
your_function
    Huge_loop
quit()
```

So it will only quit when the loop has been run.

Comment: where exactly would i put it? and also how would i word the loop?

Comment: @Arsenalfan what exactly do you mean by 'word the loop'?

Comment: could you write it out for me and where to put the statement?

Comment: Just try tabbing the loop (ident the text)

Answer (score 0):

Well because every thing is in the global scope, I'd write another Python script to run the first:

```
# run main script 10 times

for i in range(10):
    execfile('main.py')
```

Comment: yes i did consider that, but this is a assignment so I cant use that format. The loop has to be somewhere inside the script